# Problem with Gurobi java API: libgurobi95.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, gurobi

I am trying to use the Gurobi java API for the first time and I am trying to run the MIP1 example here: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/examples/mip1_java.html

I am using IntelliJ IDEA on Linux Ubuntu machine. I imported gurobi module to IntelliJ and the program build was done without errors. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ramy/gurobi950/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni95.so: libgurobi95.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1850)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
at gurobi.GurobiJni.<clinit>(GurobiJni.java:304)
at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:107)
at com.example.java.Main.main(Main.java:20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your Gurobi installation's lib path as explained in the [installation instructions of Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html).

For Gurobi 9.5, on Linux, this is typically achieved with these commands:

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi950/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that already but still the same problem. 

export GUROBI_HOME="/home/ramy/gurobi950/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
export GRB_LICENSE_FILE=/home/ramy/gurobi.lic

Comment: Please check whether the missing lib actually exists and run `ldd ${GUROBI_HOME}/lib/libGurobiJni95.so`. This will list the dependencies of the JNI lib.

Comment: The file exists. Here is the output of my command:
 'linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc74ffe000)
 libgurobi95.so => /home/ramy/gurobi950/linux64/lib/libgurobi95.so (0x00007f193c41e000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f193c21b000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f193c210000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f193c1ed000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f193c1e7000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f193c098000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f193f0d8000)'

Comment: Then this is most likely an issue with your Java compiler environment not loading these variables.

Comment: This solved my issue with the python Gurobi implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, and the environment variables are all set correctly. My solution is:

```
sudo ln -s $GUROBI_HOME/lib/libgurobi91.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s $GUROBI_HOME/lib/libGurobiJni91.so /usr/lib
sudo ldconfig
```

Then, example programs can be executed. I am using version 9.1. If there is still an error, you can try to replace $GUROBI_HOME with the real path.